# Overriding fs.permissions.umask-mode in Oozie

Tags: hadoop, oozie, umask

I'm running a Java Oozie action which runs the usual `prepare` commands of deleting and creating a folder. The created folder has a umask of `022` (the cluster default), but I want it to have `002`.

In the workflow's `job.properties` I have `fs.permissions.umask-mode=002`. If I look at the configuration being passed into the action while the job is running, this value is not used however, and the default umask of `022` is used.

`fs.permissions.umask-mode=002` is not locked within Ambari and so can be changed, and other variables within `job.properties` are correctly propogated. I've also tried unsuccessfully to put the umask property in other places such as in a `global` tag in the sub-workflow housing the action, and in the action itself.

http://grokbase.com/t/cloudera/cdh-user/134pysstcq/cdh4-2-oozie-ignores-fs-permissions-umask-mode seems to be someone else with the same issue, but the thread died.

Answer (score 0):

You may try adding following property to action in `workflow.xml`:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.permissions.umask-mode</name>
    <value>002</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

I have used it in one of my project, and it works. You may also try using old property `dfs.umask` instead of `fs.permissions.umask-mode`:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.umask</name>
    <value>2</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

OR try prefixing `oozie.launcher.` as shell actions are executed as an oozie "launcher" map tasks, and such tasks do not use normal configuration properties:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>oozie.launcher.fs.permissions.umask-mode</name>
    <value>002</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```